# How to capitalize a word in list without using python's in built methods?

Tags: python, loops

I have tried the following , which gives me the output but i want output to be in list format :

```
for i, s in enumerate(st):
        for j,ch in enumerate(s):
            if j==0:
                print(s[j].replace(s[j],s[j].upper()),end='')
            else:
                print(s[j].replace(s[j], s[j].lower()),end='')
```

Comment: sample input is st=['RAnga','test']
sample output st=['Ranga','Test']

Comment: What is there in `st`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
  stlist = []
  stlist.append(st[0].upper())
  for s in st[1:]:
    stlist.append(s.lower())
  print(stlist)
```

According to your example. Just use the above function on each element in list.

```
st=['RAnga','test']
new_st = []

for s in st:
  new_s = ''
  new_s += s[0].upper()
  for c in s[1:]:
    new_s += c.lower()
  new_st.append(new_s)

print(new_st)
```

Comment: in a list of string 
st=['RAnga','test']
sample output :
st=['Ranga','Test']